# AJAX Call passing null values to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send data to the controller using this AJAX call of type POST but it's sending null values to the controller. Through this code I want to make new records in the Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM database.

```
    
            
            var formdata = new FormData();
            var rowCount = $(".newRow").length;
            var projectarray = [];
           
            var datearray = [];
            var amountarray = [];
            
            for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                
                projectarray[i] = $("#ProjectType_" + i).val();
               
                datearray[i] = $("#ClaimExpenseDate_" + i).val();
                amountarray[i] = $("#Amount_" + i).val();
               
                

            }
            formdata.append("projectarray", projectarray);
           
            formdata.append("datearray", datearray);
            formdata.append("amountarray", amountarray);
           
            
           
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SetClaimDetails", "Claim")",
                type: "POST",
               
                data: formdata,
                
                processData: false,
               
                contenttype: false,
                    
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        
                        window.location.href = "ess/claim";
                        
                        alert("Submit Successful!");
                       

                 
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        
                        
                        window.location.href = "";
                        alert("Submit Failed!");
                       
                    }
               });
```

Here is my controller method which is storing null values instead of the values passed by the AJAX call. And because of this I'm not able to create new records in the database.

```
public ActionResult SetClaimDetails(string projectarray, string datearray, string amountarray)
        {
            try
            {
               
                Entity item = new Entity("bam_expenseclaims");
               

                item["bam_expdate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(datearray);

                item["bam_amount"] = amountarray;

                item["bam_project"] = new EntityReference("new_project", Guid.Parse(projectarray));
                
                


                globalService.Connection.Create(item);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("TechnicalErrorAppender");
                log.Error(string.Empty);
                throw ex;
            }
            
            return View(Constant.CLAIMPATH);

        }
```

Comment: Try to change your controler input parameters to this -  SetClaimDetails(string[] projectarray, string[] datearray, string[] amountarray) and change your code inside of  the controller accordingly.

Comment: The ActionResult SetClaimDetails needs 3 parameters, pass them in data during AJAX call.